# Why can’t I make a comment on posts after signing up?

Tags: support, comments

So I signed up to add a helpful comment but I can't until I earn a 50 rating. So how do I comment so I can earn a 50 rating? Confusing.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to earn *reputation* by having your questions, answers and edits up voted. (Like I just did gratuitously to your question.)

You get:

- +5 when your questions are up voted.
- +10 when your answers are up voted.
- +15 when your answers are accepted.
- +2 when your edit to other questions are approved.

Have a look at the [Welcome to Ask Different Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour), and in particular the "You earn reputation when people vote on your posts" section.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be mixing up *comments* and *answers*. If you look at the [comment everywhere privilege page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

They are supposed to be used for clarifying things, or suggesting improvements and the like. Comments are *not* for posting answers.

Answers, on the other hand, are supposed to actually provide an answer to the question. You can see [How to Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for some guidance on writing answers.

They also look pretty different. Here's what a comment looks like:

[image: comment]

And here's what an answer looks like:

[image: answer]

They are not interchangeable.

Now hopefully that's all straightened out. Welcome to Ask Different, and take the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) as @user3439894 suggested!